# What does the path "//" mean?

Tags: bash, unix, zsh

I just found the direcory `//` on my machine and now i am wondering what it means.

```
user@dev:~$ cd /
user@dev:/$ pwd
/
user@dev:/$ cd //
user@dev://$ pwd
//
```

It is obvously the root directory, but when and why do i use the double slash instead of the single slash?

Is it related to the escaped path strings which i use while programming? 
For example:

```
string path = "//home//user//foo.file"
```

I also tried it with zsh but it changes to the usual root directory `/`. So I think its bash specific.

Comment: Sounds like a bash bug or a zsh workaround ;-)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/111795

Comment: I found that article too, but that does not explain the behaviour of the bash. If you do `cd ///`, the prompt shows only one `/`.

Comment: @tmaier `///`, etc. is *explicitly* defined to be the same as `/` in the spec.

Comment: Sh does the same as bash.

Comment: Okay, but zsh does not. Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of the specification for [Pathname Resolution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12):

> A pathname consisting of a single <slash> shall resolve to the root directory of the process. A null pathname shall not be successfully resolved. If a pathname begins with two successive <slash> characters, the first component following the leading <slash> characters may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading <slash> characters shall be treated as a single <slash> character.

So your shell is just following the specification and leaving `//` alone as it *might* be implementationally defined as something other than `/`.

Comment: @tmaier For what behaviour? The path `//` doesn't get resolved to `/` (the way `////`, etc. does). Which leaves `//` up for implementation definition. bash seems to leave it alone and other shells appear to treat it as `/` (I tried `csh`, `ksh` and `zsh` on CentOS 5). Though `ksh` on my Debian unstable machine seems to leave `//` alone.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. I think the bash behaviour is more logical than the implementation of csh/ksh/zsh. Do you know if the developers had any thoughts about the specification and their corresponding implementation?

Comment: @tmaier I don't. You'd have to go look at the source/etc. to see if they mentioned it anywhere. Or try to go ask them but that's likely a decision that was made a very long time ago in most code-bases.

Comment: Thanks... that helped

Comment: Two slashes have long been used (in certain implementations) to indicate that a machine name follows.  (I recall Altos did that, in the mid-1980s). That precedes (I think...) the two backslashes used for UNC names.